# A div is spacing 1px at its left side.? A design Problem

Tags: html

Please look at:
http://jsfiddle.net/vsjwww/TT9ME/8/

It is a bit detail but its important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
margin-left:-1px;
```

In `#willslide` CSS definition.

Comment: great, it works!
i tried it once but it doesn't work.
but now its working.

anyway, thank u very much.